# TypeError on calling C# .dll API from python using pythonnet

Tags: c#, python.net

I am trying to call C# APIs from python script, while doing so, I face TypeError, saying the API, that I am trying to call via python doesn't exist. I have verified the .dll to be present in the path, and is of proper format(32 bit).Below are the details - i have added only the portions, i think to be relevant for this.

C#

```
       Signature of C# function I am trying to call 
       public status Initialization(SampleClass.CallbackDelegate callback, ushort Entries)
       present in class SampleClass
       
       where callback is of type
       
       [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
       public delegate void CallbackDelegate(IntPtr pData, SampleClass.eLogOpt bption, SampleClass.LogEntry_t[] pEntries);
```

test.py

```
       def loggercallback(ptr:pointer, option:LogObj.eLogOption, entry:LogObj.LogEntry_t):
         print(ptr)
         print(option)
         print(entry)



       print(clr.FindAssembly("libnet"))
       csharp_rdr = clr.AddReference("libnet")
       from libnet import Log
       from libnet import *

       SampleClassObj = SampleClass()
       fp_loggercallback = loggercallback

       SampleClassObj.Initialization(fp_loggercallback,32)
```

ERROR MSG:

```
     While executing test.py  
     SampleClassObj.Initialization(fp_loggercallback,32)
     TypeError: No method matches given arguments for Initialization: (<class 'function'>, <class 'int'>)
```

I am bit confused and lost, can someone help me with this.

Comment: Don't I understand something or you call the method with a different name? In C# you define the `Initialization` method, but in python you call `Init`

Comment: I am sorry, the one in python should be Initialization  - a typo